# CSS: margin auto and position absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "button" with 2 sections (each is 50% of the height of the div) separated by an horizontal bar. Each of the sections has centered text. The size of the button is going to be manipulated using javascript, and I'm trying to avoid also using javascript to position the elements inside the "button".

What I have so far is http://jsfiddle.net/u5u7d31p/2/, but i'm having a problem centering the horizontal bar. If I change the position of the separator to relative, the bar is centered, but then it changes the position of the bottom part of the text. I can also change the margin to a static value (`margin: 0 63px;`) to center it, but I would like to avoid it if there is an easier solution that doesn't require javascript.

```
.img_overlay .separator{
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #444;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All codes are ok. Just put this css below to `.img_overlay .separator` class.

Full code is below:

```
.img_overlay .separator {
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: 0;
height: 3px;
width: 70px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #444;
right: 0;
}
```

view my demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/xhuy0d5j/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img{
    float: left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 51px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img_overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #222;
    color: #ddd;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.img_overlay>div{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.img_overlay .middle{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.img_overlay .separator{
    height: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
    <div class="img_overlay">
        <div class="img_show_details">
            <div class="middle">details</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img_open">
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="middle">open</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All I did was taking off :

```css
.img_overlay .separator{
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: That is one of the "solutions" I mentioned in the question (removing position absolute), but I'm trying to avoid it because it changes the position of the "open" text, so it is no longer centered. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I personnally don't see the movement of *open*... Chrome 40, what about you ?

Comment: Using firefox 35. It goes down by 3 pixels (I think, it's probably the height of the separator). Change the height of the separator to 10px and the top to -5px, and you will probably see it more clearly.

Comment: Anyway, a `top: -1px;` is bad, because it means elements will overlap if there is no margin on the element above.

Answer (score 0):

This following fix works okay in firefox and chrome but **mess in IE**.
I fixed `height` in `div`, `top` in `middle` and `top` in `separator`

```
.img_overlay>div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.img_overlay .middle {
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.img_overlay .separator {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #444;
}
```

here's the demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/u5u7d31p/3/).